# Flot chart loading animation while rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to implement some sort of animation while a large graph gets rendered using Flot chart. I have tried numerous solutions all of which have failed.  Does anyone know if this is at all possible so the user can see that the graph is being rendered.

I have attempted to use an overlay with a loading gif but the gif does not animate until the graph has stopped rendering.

The code is being asked a lot of but I want to make sure the user can see the progress.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By your description, I'd assume flot uses the UI thread to render the graphic so the page will stay frozen until the graph has been rendered. Adapting it to use a web worker is probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: I use an animated gif to show users the graph data is loading. I don't know how you are getting the data but I use an ajax call and it works fine.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - it might be worthwhile for a large enough graph.  I've seen cases on slow machines where a fairly simple graph takes 10+ seconds to load, completely freezing the UI in the meantime

Comment: OK, didn't think this one through... you won't have access to a canvas element in a web worker, so this won't be workable

Comment: Yes, workers don't have access to the DOM. I see this kind of slow flot rendering questions quite often, maybe it would be worth requesting a rendering enhancement on the [flot repo](https://github.com/flot/flot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flot renders the whole plot in one pass on the UI thread.  There's no way to show progress without modifying the library itself.  A perfect solution would take a lot of work, but, depending on your data, a decent approximation might not require much effort.

For example, let's say your plot contains many series, and each one by itself renders pretty quickly, but together they take a long time.  In that case, if you open the Flot source and look for the draw function, you'll see that there is a simple loop calling drawSeries for each series:

```
function draw() {

    CODE BLOCK A

    for (var i = 0; i < series.length; ++i) {
        executeHooks(hooks.drawSeries, [ctx, series[i]]);
        drawSeries(series[i]);
    }

    CODE BLOCK B
}
```

Replace that with (roughly; haven't tested this) the following:

```
function draw() {

    CODE BLOCK A

    var i = 0,
        drawNextSeries = function() {
            drawSeries(series[i]);
            if (++i < series.length) {
                setTimeout(drawNextSeries, 0);
            } else {
                CODE BLOCK B
            }
        };

    setTimeout(drawNextSeries, 0);
}
```

The idea is to draw each series in a separate call via setTimeout.  The zero-millisecond delay queues up the call to run after any pending work, like other JS code, animations, etc.  So after each series draws, there's a chance for the UI to update before the next one draws.

Again, this only works if you have many series that each draw fairly quickly.  If you have just one big series, you'll still end up doing something similar, but within drawSeries.

Comment: Good proposal but cannot get this to work.  Do you have an example?

Comment: What is code block a and code block b can you put the full code as I am trying to implement with failures

Comment: Open jquery.flot.js and look for the draw function to see what those blocks are.  Again, this isn't meant to be copy-paste code.  It's just the general method; you will need to finish the implementation for your particular case.